# Advice for a nested foreach, or just displaying nested arrays

Tags: php

So for one of my older PHP class assignments, I had to take an array that contained 54 smaller arrays and print the whole thing. I am having a lot of trouble getting it to display, but I've gotten very close. So far, it displays everything perfectly, but like a million times. (Not infinite!)

I've basically just used a foreach inside a foreach, but for some reason that seems to print it like 54x54 times. I think.

Here is the array

```
$deck_individual = [
    ['black', 'spade', 'ace'],
    ['black', 'spade', 'king'],
    ['black', 'spade', 'queen'],
    ['black', 'spade', 'jack'],
    ['black', 'spade', '10'],
    ['black', 'spade', '9'],
    ['black', 'spade', '8'],
    ['black', 'spade', '7'],
    ['black', 'spade', '6'],
    ['black', 'spade', '5'],
    ['black', 'spade', '4'],
    ['black', 'spade', '3'],
    ['black', 'spade', '2'],
    ['black', 'club', 'ace'],
    ['black', 'club', 'king'],
    ['black', 'club', 'queen'],
    ['black', 'club', 'jack'],
    ['black', 'club', '10'],
    ['black', 'club', '9'],
    ['black', 'club', '8'],
    ['black', 'club', '7'],
    ['black', 'club', '6'],
    ['black', 'club', '5'],
    ['black', 'club', '4'],
    ['black', 'club', '3'],
    ['black', 'club', '2'],
    ['red', 'heart', 'ace'],
    ['red', 'heart', 'king'],
    ['red', 'heart', 'queen'],
    ['red', 'heart', 'jack'],
    ['red', 'heart', '10'],
    ['red', 'heart', '9'],
    ['red', 'heart', '8'],
    ['red', 'heart', '7'],
    ['red', 'heart', '6'],
    ['red', 'heart', '5'],
    ['red', 'heart', '4'],
    ['red', 'heart', '3'],
    ['red', 'heart', '2'],
    ['red', 'diamond', 'ace'],
    ['red', 'diamond', 'king'],
    ['red', 'diamond', 'queen'],
    ['red', 'diamond', 'jack'],
    ['red', 'diamond', '10'],
    ['red', 'diamond', '9'],
    ['red', 'diamond', '8'],
    ['red', 'diamond', '7'],
    ['red', 'diamond', '6'],
    ['red', 'diamond', '5'],
    ['red', 'diamond', '4'],
    ['red', 'diamond', '3'],
    ['red', 'diamond', '2'],
    ['red', 'wild', 'joker'],
    ['black', 'wild', 'joker']
];
```

And here is the loop(s) I've used.

```
foreach ($deck_individual as $help)
                {
                  foreach ($deck_individual as $help)
                  {
                    echo $help[0];
                    echo $help[1];
                    echo $help[2];
                    echo "<br>";

                  }
                }
```

Right now it looks like this:

```
blackspadeace
blackspadeking
blackspadequeen
blackspadejack
blackspade10
blackspade9
blackspade8
blackspade7
blackspade6
blackspade5
blackspade4
blackspade3
blackspade2
blackclubace
blackclubking
blackclubqueen
blackclubjack...
```

and so on, except it displays the whole thing and then does it another million times. I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: Please don't include tags that are unrelated to your problem itself. I've removed the `atom-editor` tag, it's irrelevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is running 54x54 times as you are running the same loop inside the parent loop. Try changing your loop to the following:

```
foreach ($deck_individual as $help)
{
  foreach ($help as $item)
  {
    echo $item;
  }
  echo "<br>";
}
```